# A number root of two irreducible polynomials?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, divisibility

I woke up today doing me a question:

is there a complex number that is root of two different irreducible polynomials of $\mathbb{Q} [x]$?

I think not but I'm not sure and I am trying to prove. Some help?

Comment: This might be easier to answer if you say a little more about what you already know.  For example, if I were to refer to the ring homomorphism $f_\alpha:\Bbb Z[x]\to \Bbb C$, would I need to explain that?

Comment: By the way, the answer to your question is yes, if you restrict the question to irreducible *monic* polynomials.  For if not, then clearly $1$ is a root of both $x-1$ and $2x-2$.

Comment: @MJD: Thanks. I edit in order to have the "true question".

Comment: The answer is the same, and you still need “monic”, as the same example shows.

Comment: @MJD: Is not 2 a unit in spite of appearances?

Comment: Maybe our definitions are different. Mine is that a polynomial is irreducible if it is not the product of two non-constant polynomials. Under this definition, all first-degree polynomials are irreducible.

Comment: Nobody doubts that. What I mean is that in Q [x] all nonzero rational is a unit and therefore x-1 and 2x-2 are the same irreducible polynomial.

Comment: @Luis RIght, they are associates, i.e. differ by a unit multiple. Often we normalize by choosing a rep that is monic (lead coef $= 1)\,$ from the class of all associates of $\,f(x).\ \ $

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint** $\ f_1(r) = 0 = f_2(r)\,\Rightarrow \gcd(f_1,f_2)(r) = 0\,$ by $\,\gcd(f_1,f_2) = h_1 f_1\! + h_2 f_2\,$ by Bezout.

Comment: I feel you are in the right way, however I don't understand $\gcd(f_1,f_2)(r) = 0$ (please, is it in the domaine of numbers?, for Bézout, no problem).

Comment: @Luis in $\,\Bbb Q[x]\,$ we have an (extended) Euclidean algorithm. Thus if $\,g = \gcd(f_1,f_2)\,$ then $\,g(x) = h_1(x) f_1(x) + h_2(x) f_2(x)\, $ for some $\,h_i \in \Bbb Q[x].\,$ Evaluating that at $\,x=r\,$ yields $\,g(r) = 0,\,$ since $\,f_1(r) = 0 = f_2(r).\ \ $

Comment: I know everything you say. Forgive me that I'm not exactly clear at this time but I think that does not answer the question. Finally, r may or may not be root of different irreducible $f_1$ and $f_2$?

Comment: @Luis $\ $ It is a (big) hint. Further hint: if $\,f_1,f_2\,$ are nonassociate irreducibles then what is their gcd?

Comment: @Luis .e.g. a common root of $\,f_1 \!= x^3\!+x+1\,$ and $\,f_2 = x^2\!+1\,$ is a root of their gcd $\, f_1 \!- x f_2 = 1,\,$ contradiction.

Comment: So, it is not possible as I suspected. Thank you very much, Bill.